# bash script to read informations from pdf

Tags: pdf, pdftotext

I have a bunch of pdf files. I would like to create a file containing informations about this pdf's like authors and title. Is it possible to write a script (preferably in bash) which automatize this?

Comment: I assume that you're on Linux (given that you mention `bash`).  You could get [`xpdf`](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/); it contains a utility called `pdfinfo` which provides metadata information for a PDF.

Comment: "Unfortunately" I have a mac

Comment: @user65187: Than install it through MacPorts or so. http://apple.stackexchange.com/ can help.